# How to jump upwards in easymotion plugin for VIM?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

How to jump to the lines above the cursor while using the easymotion plugin in vim?

Comment: Your desktop looks good but I can't see a damn thing in this tiny window. Try adding a code sample to your question instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`<leader><leader>f` will search forward while `<leader><leader>F` will search backward (and such upward!). Same with `t` and `T`.

This is analogous to standard Vim motion `f` / `F`

This is all explained in `:help easymotion.txt`

Answer (score 19):

To search *words* backwards use `<Leader><Leader>b`
Try `<Leader><Leader>B` to search *WORDS*

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between two? Documentation has similar description for both, except one searches for *words* and other for *WORDS*. But what is the difference between words and WORDS in this context?

Comment: For anyone else who might come to this thread in the future, and is curious about this as I was: The difference is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390519/whats-the-difference-between-b-and-b-in-vim

The key takeaway is: "The difference is that vim considers a "word" to be letters, numbers, and underscores [...], but a "WORD" is always anything that isn't whitespace."

Comment: It is actually <Leader><Leader> b .