# What's the difference between b and B in Vim?

Tags: vim

I googled and that's what it says:

To go back a word, b is used. Once again, B will include more characters in what Vim considers a word.

I didn't understand what B does different from b. Can you give me an example to make it clear for me to understand? Thanks.

[EDIT]Actually I wonder this because in the online vim [game](http://vim-adventures.com/), I tried to go back to WORDS from ! with b, but it didn't work. However when I tried it with Vim installed in my computer, it worked with b. So is this only for to make player use B with the help of clue?

Here is the picture of game:

[image]

Comment: Google is not where you should go when you want an explanation for a Vim feature: learn to use `:help`. The answers to most of your questions are there. Also, you **need** to go through `$ vimtutor`. It is much more useful than that game.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Like most of the capitalized movement pairs, <kbd>b</kbd> moves by word, but <kbd>B</kbd> moves by WORD.  The difference is that vim considers a "word" to be letters, numbers, and underscores (and you can configure this with the `iskeyword` setting), but a "WORD" is *always* anything that isn't whitespace.

So given this:

```
foo-bar-baz
```

If your cursor is on the `z` and you press <kbd>b</kbd>, the cursor will move back to the start of `baz`, then to the hyphen, then back to the start of `bar`, and so on.  Each of these is a different "word" to vim: `foo`, `-`, `bar`, `-`, `baz`.

But if you press <kbd>B</kbd>, the cursor will move all the way left to the `f`, because `foo-bar-baz` is all non-whitespace and thus a single WORD.

`:help word` inside vim explains this too.

---

Regarding the vim game: I think the game treats boulders as punctuation.  Try typing it in vim like this:

```
not WORDS*!
```

With the cursor on `!`, <kbd>b</kbd> will move you back to the `*`, because `*!` is all punctuation and thus one word.  But that `*` is actually a boulder, so you can't move there, so nothing happens.  <kbd>B</kbd>, on the other hand, will skip you back over everything that isn't a space.

Comment: also have a look at `:help iskeyword`

Comment: Can you answer my last question in the edited one above, please?

Answer (score 9):

B treats punctuation as part of the word, using only whitespace as word delimiters; b does not treat punctuation as part of the word.